# How to read excel data starting from specific col

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets and I am trying to import/read the data starting from an empty col.

the row data look like this

| A |  | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

and I am trying to get the data

|  | C |
| --- | --- |
| Two | Three |

I can't use usecols as the position of this empty col changes in each sheet I have in the workbook.

I have tried this but didn't work out for me.

```
df = df[~df.header.shift().eq('').cummax()]
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints. Mant thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to start from the first empty header, then:

```
df = df[df.columns[list(df.columns).index('Unnamed: 1'):]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that! the col name is also changing in the sheets as sometimes you have some empty cols at col A. Is there a way to read the col starting from col C -1 (always the col before C). Sorry for not being clear in my question

Comment: So, you want to read starting from column C - 1? Is the `C` used consistently? I.e., same label is used throughout all sheets? If it is, you can just modify this part `index('C') - 1`. Notice the `-1` which shifts it one column to the left of `C`

Comment: Thanks a mil! this is working!